# Failed to start service, datasource is already registered

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, datasource

I'm using JBoss 7.1 to deploy a maven application. I defined a new mySQL datasource in the standalone.xml just like this:

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/customss-upnxt-service-providersDS" pool-name="customss-upnxt-service-providersDS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

When deploying, I got this error:

```
14:14:25,428 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."customss-upnxt-service-providers.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."customss-upnxt-service-providers.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "customss-upnxt-service-providers.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS010464: Exception deploying datasource java:jboss/datasources/customss-upnxt-service-providersDS
at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentInstallProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentInstallProcessor.java:125)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.customss-upnxt-service-providersDS is already registered
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
```

Any hint? 
I'm new to jBoss & I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try to change JNDI name?

Comment: should I change it every time I deploy? I'm getting also another duplication error regarding my .war file: ERROR: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"myProject.war\")]"}}

Comment: No you don't need to change is every time. regarding duplicate resource of your WAR. it it coming because earlier version is not un-deployed. Either you can undeploy it first or delete tmp folder  before restarting server.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and solved it by deleting the datasource configuration file `SampleJavaEE6\ear\src\main\application\META-INF\`SampleJavaEE6-ds.xml`.

Here's my situation: I have a couple of apps on my workstation running on JBoss EAP 6.2.0 (based on JBoss AS7). Both of them were started using a Maven Archetype that is a quickstart for Java EE 6 apps. I could build and deploy them from the IDE (JBoss Developer Studio) but when I tried deploying the second one from the command line with `C:> mvn jboss-as:deploy` I got the datasource already registered error.

- because they both came from similar archetypes, they both had a persistence unit named `primary` even thought the data sources had different names
- the one that was failing was using the H2 example database that ships with JBoss. It was originally configured in `EAP_HOME\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`, but the second app also had it configured in `PROJECT_ROOT\ear\src\main\application\META-INF\SampleJavaEE6-ds.xml`

I never figured out why it was failing even though the datasource names were different, ...something to do with the persistence units with the same name.

I assumed that the IDE installed the second datasouce, undeploy does not remove it, and that the command line was trying to re-install it every time I tried to deploy. I realized that the datasource in `standalone.xml` was good enough, since I only need it in the short term anyway. So, I deleted the config file, `SampleJavaEE6-ds.xml`, that was being packaged in the `EAR` and made sure the datasouce configured in persistence.xml pointed to the one in `standalone.xml`.

Soon I'll replace it all with a real database which I will configure a connection to in 'standalone.xml`.

Comment: still with the same error here even after I remove <name>ds.xml from the project and let it only in standalone.xml..

Comment: run maven clean install outside the IDE after remove the file as solved the problem for me. Seems like eclipse can't handle this deletion on target folder